# extracting text from a pdf in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, text-extraction

I am trying to extract text from a PDF.

```
def getPDFContent(path):
    p = open(path, "rb")
    print(p)
    content = ""
    pdf_content = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(p)
    print(pdf_content)
    pages = pdf_content.numPages
    print(pages)
    for i in range(0, pages):
        content += pdf_content.getPage(i).extractText() + "\n"
        #print(content)
    content = " ".join(content.replace(u"\xa0", " ").strip().split())
    return content

getPDFContent(path_to_sample)
```

The output I get is:

[image]

How can that be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

Your first mistake is not having a variable assigned to your function call where it return the processed text.

> x=getPDFContent(path_to_sample)

If that still doesn't fix the problem:
Try Using The module PDF Miner.(PDF Miner.Six for Python 3). PyPDF2 can sometimes be problematic depending on which version of Python you use. I faced issues with PyPDF2 with certain PDF files which gave me a similar oytput to yours. However PDFMiner has worked with the following code consistently with Python 3.xx.

Download PDFMiner with the command: `pip install pdfminer.six` for Python 2+3 compatibility and use the following code below and you should be good to go.

```
    from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
    pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
    from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
    from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
    def getPDFContent(path,pages=None):
         pdf_str=""
         if not pages:
           pagenums = set()
         else:
           pagenums = set(pages)
    output = io.StringIO()
    manager = PDFResourceManager()
    converter = TextConverter(manager, output, laparams=LAParams())
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(manager, converter)
    infile = open(path, 'rb')
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(infile, pagenums):
        interpreter.process_page(page)
    infile.close()
    converter.close()
    text = output.getvalue()
    pdf_str=text     
    output.close()
    return(pdf_str)
    x=getPDFContent(path_to_sample)
```